# How to access MySQL when I delete the root user on openSUSE 11?

Tags: linux, php, mysql

Unfortunately, I deleted MySQL users with the command `delete from mysql.user` and now I can't access MySQL. I tried looking at [MySQL - ERROR 1045 - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied), but it is not proper for me because I don't have any user for MySQL.

I uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL but can't access MySQL; What should I do? I wanted to have `phpMyAdmin` without login and I ruined the whole thing.

After uninstalling and having no result, I tried to delete the directories of MySQL and reinstall them, but again no result, and now I have this error:

```
Error 2002: can't connect to local mysql server through socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I don't have any user to reset the password of, but if I have to reinstall, I don't know how to connect to MySQL, and have tried:

- `MySQL -u root`
- `MySQL`
- `mysqld-safe`, etc. in the link

Comment: Your title says you deleted `root` but you mention `mysql` which account did you delete exactly.  If it wasn't `root` just use `root` to add a new `mysql` user.

Comment: I issued this command delete from mysql.users so I deleted the whole users

Comment: I screwed the whole

Comment: I restarted the system and it finally goes to the system I don't know what the hell is happening here

Comment: What about a fresh MySQL install in a different directory (or computer) and then replacing the data files (empty) with your old ones?

Comment: Do you already have user data in the database ??? What version of MySQL are you running ???

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to recommend something more secure:

1. Create a file that puts back the `root@localhost` with the password `wh@t3v3r`

   ```bsh
   cd /var/lib/mysql
   echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost " > InitFile.sql
   echo "IDENTIFIED BY 'wh@t3v3r';" >> InitFile.sql
   ```
2. Add the following to `/etc/my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` group

   ```bsh
   [mysqld]
   init-file=/var/lib/mysql/InitFile.sql
   ```
3. `service mysql restart`
4. Remove `init-file=/var/lib/mysql/InitFile.sql` from `/etc/my.cnf`
5. `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/InitFile.sql`

You can connect to `mysql` like this:

```bsh
mysql -uroot -p <hit enter>
Password: <type password wh@t3v3r and hit enter>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqld` has a **`--skip-grant-tables`** option; you may try restarting it that way, then you'd restore data from a backup.